# how to insert bulk into the fact table in redshift

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, amazon-redshift

I am interested in exapanding the fact tables so that they contain 2 billion rows. What do you think is the best way to do this? For example, do we take a year of data, and copy back into the same table, but change the dates for a subsequent year? What I mean is, taking 2010 data and making it 2011 data, or something like that. Thoughts?

Regards,

Comment: What does this have to do with Oracle?

Comment: I removed Oracle and Postgres tags, because the question is explicitly about Red Shift.

Comment: I need to know the best approach to do this, that's why I thought to bigger the audience better the chance to get best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is how I've done it within Redshift for testing on large datasets, something like:

`INSERT INTO factTable (factdate, columns...)
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, factdate), columns...
FROM factTable;`

Then you can run this multiple times either changing the -1 value or keeping it the same if you're happy duplicating data.

Redshift is very fast performing inserts like this, if you're doubling your dataset each time you execute the statement you'll get to a large enough table pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi,
I'll check this back to you. Any other method would you like to share.
Regards,